# using Nullable DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I wanted to assign null value to DateTime type in c#, so I used:

```
public DateTime? LockTime;
```

When LockTime is not assigned LockTime.Value contains null by default.
I want to be able to change LockTime.Value to null after it has been assigned other value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if `LockTime` hasn't been assigned a value, it will be the nullable value by default - so  `LockTime.Value` will throw an exception if you try to access it.

You can't assign null to `LockTime.Value` itself, firstly because it's read-only and secondly because the type of `LockTime.Value` is the *non-nullable* `DateTime` type.

However, you can set the value of the variable to be the null value in several different ways:

```
LockTime = null; // Probably the most idiomatic way
LockTime = new DateTime?();
LockTime = default(DateTime?);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could assign `null` directly to the variable (the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property is readonly and it cannot be assigned a value):

```
LockTime = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried LockTime = null?

Answer (score 2):

The `Value` porperty is readonly, so you can't assign a value to it. What you *can* do is to assign null to the `LockTime` field:

```
LockTime = null;
```

However, this will create a new `DateTime?` instance, so any other pieces of code having a reference to the original `LockTime` instance will not see this change. This is nothing strange, it's the same thing that would happen with a regular `DateTime`, so it's just something your code has to deal with gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

```
     DateTime? nullableDT = null;
     Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", nullableDT.HasValue, nullableDT);
     nullableDT = DateTime.Now;
     Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", nullableDT.HasValue, nullableDT);
     nullableDT = null;
     Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", nullableDT.HasValue, nullableDT);
     /*
     False
     True    30.07.2010 11:17:59
     False
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define  the variable this way:

```
private Nullable<DateTime> _assignedDate;  
_assignedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

and then assign a null value:

```
_assignedDate = null;
```